# Would Smeagol have been permitted passage into Valinor had he lived?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gollum

If Frodo successfully redeemed Smeagol, who did not fall back into becoming Gollum again, then would Smeagol - technically a Ring-bearer - be permitted into Valinor like Frodo and Sam after the Ring is destroyed?